# Running a SAS 9.2 program inside a C# project ?

Tags: c#, sas

I'm running SAS batch files daily but since SAS files are not compiled, they are available for viewing by simply opening the files with Notepad.

I was wondering if I could run a .SAS file from within a C# project, hence hiding the SAS code.

Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: I think it's important to note that .NET assemblies are very, very easy to reverse engineer with [freely available tools](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/). Even with C#, you'd still need an obfuscator.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hide your SAS code, there are a few ways to do it without something quite so complicated.  This topic is well covered here:
https://communities.sas.com/thread/34604?start=0&tstart=0

Stored programs and compiled macros are two very good solutions here; they're fairly easy to implement and allow you to deploy your code (just like a C# project or whatever) with a minimum of extra work.